# In R, how to take combinations of four sets in such a way that each combination should not include elements from same set?

Tags: r

I am explaining my question through an example.

suppose I have four sets, say, (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9),(10,11,12) and all the elements are unique.

I want to generate each possible combinations of four sets in such a way that the combination should not include elements from same set. In my example, the combinations will be:

```
{1}, {2},...,{12},{1,4},{1,5},...,{9,12},{1,4,7},{1,4,8},...,{6,9,12},{1,4,7,10},...,{3,6,9,12}
```

In my actual problem, the total number of sets is 90

I am unable to generate R code for this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider accepting the solutions to your questions.

Comment: Do all your 90 sets contain 3 consecutive numbers as in your first example? This will surely cause memory issues as the number of permutations will be gigantic.

Answer (score 3):

First, construct a list of the sets, eg :

```
set1 <- c(1,2,3)
set2 <- c(4,5,6)
set3 <- c(7,8,9)
set4 <- c(10,11,12)
set <- list(set1,set2,set3,set4)
```

The difficulty is that you want samples of different lenghts. In the simple case that you wanted all combinations containing one from each set, it would be easy:

```
expand.grid (set)
```

But you also want all combinations with one, two or three elements. So we have to make a list of all possible ways to combine 1,2,3 and 4:

```
icombo <- list()
lapply(1:4,function(i){icombo <<- c(icombo,combn(c(1,2,3,4),i,simplify=FALSE))})
```

And then use that list to index your set and feed it into expand.grid:

```
lapply(icombo,function(x){ expand.grid (set[x])  } )
```

That should do the trick :-)

Comment: Actually in my problem total number of sets is 90. In that case R is taking large time to compute all the permutations

Comment: @user3642360 You'd need to specify that in your question, it's not an insignificant detail!!

Comment: hehe - if there are 3 items in each of the 90 sets, the number of combinations would be 3^90 or 8.72E42 + all the combinations with 89 items, 88, 87 etc. Way beyond the possibilities of any present-day computer to generate :-)

Answer (score 0):

Package `gtools` allows generating permutations that we'll use as indices:

```
library(gtools)
perm <- permutations(n = 4, r=4, v = c(1, 2, 3, NA), set = FALSE, 
                     repeats.allowed = TRUE)
```

Declare the list of sets, that we store in a list for convenience.

```
 my.set <- list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12)
```

`perm` will look like this (20 first lines shows)

```
perm[1:20,]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    2
 [3,]    1    1    1    3
 [4,]    1    1    1   NA
 [5,]    1    1    2    1
 [6,]    1    1    2    2
 [7,]    1    1    2    3
 [8,]    1    1    2   NA
 [9,]    1    1    3    1
[10,]    1    1    3    2
[11,]    1    1    3    3
[12,]    1    1    3   NA
[13,]    1    1   NA    1
[14,]    1    1   NA    2
[15,]    1    1   NA    3
[16,]    1    1   NA   NA
[17,]    1    2    1    1
[18,]    1    2    1    2
[19,]    1    2    1    3
[20,]    1    2    1   NA
```

Next we'll use those permutations to extract, in turn, each value from `my.set`. Either with a **for loop** (even though the trend is to try to avoid them as much as possible, they can still be very useful and straightforward to use):

```
# Initialise empty list to store results
resulst <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(perm)) {
  resulst[[length(resutls)+1]] <- as.numeric(na.omit(c(my.set[[1]][perm[i,1]],
                                               my.set[[2]][perm[i,2]],
                                               my.set[[3]][perm[i,3]],
                                               my.set[[4]][perm[i,4]])))
}
```

Or without a loop, using **lapply**:

```
resuslt <- lapply(1:(nrow(perm)-1), FUN = function(i) {
                  as.numeric(na.omit(c(my.set[[1]][perm[i,1]],
                                       my.set[[2]][perm[i,2]],
                                       my.set[[3]][perm[i,3]],
                                       my.set[[4]][perm[i,4]])))
           })

head(results)
[[1]]
[1]  1  4  7 10

[[2]]
[1]  1  4  7 11

[[3]]
[1]  1  4  7 12

[[4]]
[1] 1 4 7

[[5]]
[1]  1  4  8 10

[[6]]
[1]  1  4  8 11
```